# Why the ROC is all s? (Signals & System)

Tags: laplace-transform, conversion

The problem from mit ocw signals and systems (open for everyone)

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-003-signals-and-systems-fall-2011/

Sorry, I tried to write it Latex, but it doesn't work well.
Sorry that I upload the picture

What I want to ask is why the ROC is all s. I think the answer is "Re(s) > 0"

[image: problem capture]

Comment: Uploading a picture is fine. Latex for \$\frac{1}{3}\$ =  `\$\frac{1}{3}\$` as an example. `\$` is the key to beginning and ending latex on this site.